# Accessing a Computer on a network from elsewhere in the internet

Tags: networking, web-hosting, dynamic-ip

What I am trying to do is setup a Server that relays information. The Server will be on a dynamic IPAddress on a Virtual Computer over at Amazon via Amazon web hosting. My question is: is it possible for the server to access my Computer on my network at my house? The Computer has a static IPAddress, which is not dynamic. I know it is obviously possible for my Computer to access the Virtual Computer at Amazon, but what about the other way around? If I have a server running on my Computer at my house is it possible for the Virtual Computer at Amazon to create a connection between it and my Computer?

Comment: What type of connection?

Comment: Its a TCP connection

Comment: Well that narrows it down. If the server has the ability to make an outbound connection to the tuple (detination address and port) of your computer, and your computer/firewall allows inbound connections to that port, then yes it's possible.

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened? What didn't happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible - we have replication working between our Amazon instance and local machines.

We're using our routers for this, and what we use is an end to end VPN tunnel between the networks (so between our edge router and Amazon).

An alternate solution is to set up an ssh server service, and have the remote server scp the data downstream. (This should work for Linux and Windows)

You could also open a samba share to the internet and have the Amazon virtual connect to it as a scheduled task/cron job.